# Decoding JSON in PHP can't access keys

Tags: php, decode, json

I have the JSON result:

```
[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5237d438e4b07666dcca4896"} , 
    "username" : "user" , "password" : "asdf"} ]
```

That is returned from a GET request. I am trying to decode this result, I can't seem to access the username or password keys. This is what I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($result[0]);
echo $obj->username;
```

However it seems to return the entire result(the array) every time.

Comment: The result is the same whether I use the `0` index or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a second parameter boolan true to json_decode
like

```
$obj = json_decode($result[0], true);
```

Then you will get associative array instead of an object.

and can access values through keys like

```
echo $obj['username'];
```

Comment: He wants to access values direct with their keys like username and password.

Comment: As I can see from his tryings, he wants to access them as objects, not arrays

Comment: I just gave a solution to access values with the keys directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json[0]->username;
```

Full example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$result = '[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5237d438e4b07666dcca4896"} , 
    "username" : "user" , "password" : "asdf"} ]';

$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json[0]->username;
?>
```

Result:

```
user
```

Comment: You cant access to object with `0` index.

Comment: @Bora globally $obj is an array containing objects

Comment: @Bora fixed to be more understandable.

Comment: I missed the `[]` brackets sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = '[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5237d438e4b07666dcca4896"} , 
    "username" : "user" , "password" : "asdf"} ]';
$obj = json_decode($result);
var_dump($obj);
/**
 * Array containg object. So now $obj is just an array
 * 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public '_id' => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public '$oid' => string '5237d438e4b07666dcca4896' (length=24)
      public 'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
      public 'password' => string 'asdf' (length=4)
 * 
 * 
 * Key 0 contains object properties _id; username; password
 * 

 */

echo $obj[0]->username;  // user
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right json_decode function returns an array. You need to fetch value from that array. In above case you need to fetch username like below:

```
echo $json_encode[0]->username;;
```

depends upon your json.

[You can refer this link:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: It returns an array, but username is not an array key